# Adding items in an array of strings each one at a time

Tags: powershell, command, invoke

I have this line of code:

```
invoke-command -Session $s -scriptblock {Set-Adgroup  $using:ListBox1.SelectedItem -add @{proxyaddresses="$using:smtps"}}
```

$s is legitimate session, $listbox.selecteditem is for example a dist group called Old-Sales-Users , and $smtps is a string array like so:
@smtps = "smtp:bla@bla.bla", "smtp:bla2@bla.bla", "smtp:bla3@bla.bla"

i want to invoke this command so i can add those smtps to the proxyaddresses of the dist group. but the way this works here is that its adding the 3 strings to the same line so i get one line proxyaddress with "smtp:bla@bla.bla smtp:bla2@bla...." i want it to create 3 seperate lines (or more if there's more in that array) meaning like an ENTER is pressed after each item in the array... my second question is if thats the correct way to be doing this? because i actually open 3 invoke commands is there a way using 1 invoke command to add all that array to the proxyaddress?

Thank you

Comment: Remove the `"` double-quotes around `$using:smpts`

Comment: it will throw an error: Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'.
Parameter name: proxyaddresses
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (OldIT:ADGroup) [Set-ADGroup], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADGroup
    + PSComputerName        : dc01

Comment: That's a problem with the object referenced by `$using:ListBox1.SelectedItem`, maybe try `$GroupName = $ListBox1.SelectedItem.DistinguishedName` and then pass `$using:GroupName` to `Set-ADGroup` inside the remote script block

Comment: that could work i guess but i need to change more code lines for that cuz $listbox1.selecteditems are just strings when we get here, is there no way to pass array of strings and reach each of them for itself? im guessing a solution would be a loop going inside the array and invoking command for every item but thats like an overkill ithink

Comment: Try `-Add @{proxyaddresses= [string[]]$using:smtps}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post my comment as answer:

Although this is not clear in the documentation for [Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps#parameters), adding items to the `ProxyAddresses` list needs the array of new smtp addresses to be **strongly typed**, so every item in the array is of type `[string]`

This means the array to add needs to be casted with `[string[]]`

You can see the difference like this:

```
$arr1 = 'an','array','can','also','contain','numbers',1,2,3
$arr1.GetType().FullName  # --> System.Object[]

[string[]]$arr2 = 'an','array','can','also','contain','numbers',1,2,3
$arr2.GetType().FullName  # --> System.String[]
```

In your case, use

```
-Add @{proxyaddresses= [string[]]$using:smtps}
```

Comment: Or when he sets smtps, he should set it with the `[string[]]` tag...Powershell is a weakly typed language, meaning it will attempt to detect the type of variable you are setting, (as opposed to strongly typed). Sometimes it get's it wrong, so identifying it yourself can remove any possible errors that might arise..Because his example starts with `@smtps = "bla"` the `@smtps =` might be confusing powershell.